# Is it safe to eat cooked food that falls on the stove top?

Tags: food-safety

Ex) I cooked rice and was scooping it out of the pot and a some of it fell on the stove top. Should I discard of this rice or is it okay to eat?

Comment: How clean is your stove top?

Answer (score 5):

I consider my stove top the same as my counter top.  If I drop food on a clean counter top, I have no problem scooping it up and using it.  On the other hand, if, for example, I had just been preparing raw chicken on my counter top, I would not.  Your stove top is no different.  This is simply about cleanliness.

Comment: Well it is also a bit about how much rice "some of it" is. If 6 grains of rice fell from pot, then there is no trouble just trashing them. If half the pot of rice fell on the stove top, then you have to think seriously about using the spilt rice.